# DSB on ARM Cortex M4 processors

Tags: arm

I have read the ARM documentation and it appears that they say in some places that the Cortex M4 can reorder memory writes, while in other places it indicates that M4 will not.

Specifically I am wondering if the DBM instruction is needed like:

```
volatile int flag=0; 
char buffer[10]; 
void foo(char c)
{     
      __ASM volatile ("dbm" : : : "memory");
      __disable_irq(); //disable IRQ as we use flag in ISR
    buffer[0]=c;
    flag=1;
      __ASM volatile ("dbm" : : : "memory");
      __enable_irq(); 
}
```

Comment: Note I am asking this question as that all the example code I have seen does not use the DBM before __disable_irq() and __enable_irq().  So I wanted to know if it should be there or not?  Also I wanted to know when the DBM should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, it depends on what your flag is, and it also varies from chip to chip.

In case that flag is stored in memory:

DSB is not needed here. An interrupt handler that would access flag would have to load it from memory first. Even if your previous write is still in progress the CPU will make sure that the load following the store will happen in the correct order.

If your flag is stored in peripheral memory:

Now it gets interesting. Lets assume flag is in some hardware peripheral. A write to it may make an interrupt pending or acknowledge an interrupt (aka clear a pending interrupt). Contrary to the memory example above this effect happens without the CPU having to read the flag first. So the automatic ordering of stores and loads won't help you. Also writes to flag may take effect with a surprisingly long delay due to different clock domains between the CPU and the peripheral.

So the following szenario can happen:

- you write `flag=1` to clear an handled interrupt.
- you enable interrupts by calling `__enable_irq()`
- interrupts get enabled, write to flag=1 is still pending.
- wheee, an interrupt is pending and the CPU jumps to the interrupt handler.
- `flag=1` takes effect. You're now in an interrupt handler without anything to do.

Executing a DSB in front of `__enable_irq()` will prevent this problem because whatever is triggered by `flag=1` will be in effect before `__enable_irq()` executes.

If you think that this case is purely academic: Nope, it's real.

Just think about a real-time clock. These usually runs at 32khz. If you write into it's peripheral space from a CPU running at 64Mhz it can take a whopping 2000 cycles before the write takes effect. Now for real-time clocks the data-sheet usually shows specific sequences that make sure you don't run into this problem.

The same thing can however happen with slow peripherals.

My personal anecdote happened when implementing power-saving late in a project. Everything was working fine. Then we reduced the peripheral clock speed of I²C and SPI peripherals to the lowest possible speed we could get away with. This can save lots of power and extend battery live. What we found out was that suddenly interrupts started to do unexpected things. They seem to fire twice each time wrecking havoc. Putting a DSB at the end of each affected interrupt handler fixed this because - you can guess - the lower clock speed caused us to leave the interrupt handlers before clearing the interrupt source was in effect due to the slow peripheral clock.

Comment: This use of DSB sounds like a good use.  I am wondering how the core knows that the write across a clock domain happened?

Comment: Nils, did your part have a data cache enabled?

Comment: @Trampas that part only had cache for for code to compensate for the small flash. RAM on-chip SRAM, so no cache needed.

Comment: So I guess with the ARM instruction pipeline it stalled the bus to the peripheral but it still could exit the the interrupt service handler.  Hence the DMB was needed.  I know that Atmel does some crazy stuff with their peripherals and have local sync bits due to clock differences.  I think they may have a local cache of the registers which operate at core speeds, and then peripheral updates happen later.

Comment: @Trampas I think the point is: If you write multiple registers, most of the time you only care about the order, not the exact moment when the writes take effect. So if you put the logic into the chip and have a synchronization over the clock-domains on every single write you'll pay the penalty for each peripheral access. Having a DMB at the end solves the problem with only one single stall.

Comment: I'm curious whether the approach of "putting a DSB at the end of each interrupt handler" was actually a real fix for whatever was going on.  The Cortex-M application note 321 "Programming Guide to Memory Barrier Instructions" states that "In addition to the ISB instruction, the architecture defines exception entry and exception return
to also have ISB semantics, causing a fresh fetch of instructions and a re-evaluation of interrupts."  Since ISB is stricter even than DSB, how could an extra DSB have helped?

Answer (score 0):

This section of the [Cortex M4 generic device user guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDHHFCC.html) enumerates the factors which can affect reordering.

- the processor can reorder some memory accesses to improve efficiency, providing this does not affect the behavior of the instruction sequence.
- the processor has multiple bus interfaces
- memory or devices in the memory map have different wait states
- some memory accesses are buffered or speculative.

You should also bear in mind that both DSB and ISB are often required (in that order), and that C does not make any guarantees about the ordering (except in-thread volatile accesses).

You will often observe that the short pipeline and instruction sequences can combine in such a way that the race conditions seem unreachable with a specific compiled image, but this isn't something you can rely on. Either the timing conditions might be rare (but possible), or subsequent code changes might change the resulting instruction sequence.

Comment: I have read several things in the ARM documentation.  Including that since my processor is a single core, and even with cache it will not reorder memory access or instructions.  However at the same time DSB and ISBs are recommended to make code more portable to future processors.    I have also read like link above that it is possible that memory access happens out of order, especially when you have wait states on memory.

Comment: There are certainly scenarios with a single cpu like this where DSB/ISB is not just for portability.

Comment: do you have examples where DMB, DSB, ISB should be used on single core M4?

Comment: Enabling the FPU, Programming the MPU, changing the SP. Not always, but you can find cases if you try.

Comment: @Trampas The AN321 "Programming Guide to Memory Barrier Instructions" explicitly states that "All use of DMB is redundant due to the inherent ordering of all loads and stores on Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M4.", so we can at least ignore that one (if choosing not to support portability to other architectures).

Comment: @PeterHansen  Yes I have read the same thing...  I have started added the DMB just to be clear and have code portability. I also have found that clearing interrupt flags in vendor peripherals are a mess, especially across clock domains and with peripheral caching.  Do not trust the vendor peripherals as they often do not document caching and often when they do it is wrong.  As such I learned to write defensive code, hence adding DMB...